# Is it safe to rely on Func.GetHashCode for a set of Func definitions?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable

I have a number of `Func` definitions (like 30) that checks for things, for instance:

```
IsLayerEnabled
IsEffectEnabled
...
```

I want to hash these in a Dictionary. Is it safe to just use:

```
IsLayerEnabled.GetHashCode()
etc
```

for each Func definition?

Or would they be the same hash value for each?

Comment: How are you planning to **use** the Func within the dictionary?  What would the Dictionary's declaration and usage look like?

Comment: That's a good question. I haven't thought that far I think. Now I realize, I wouldn't be able to use Func (without type params) as the value of the Dictionary, right?

Comment: If it's going to be the value in the dictionary, the hash code will never be used... Hash code's are only used for Dictionary **keys**...

Comment: They will be used as keys actually. I just wanted to make it like provide an id and get the Func, but for ids I was thinking of using Func def's hash value. I think my thinking is flawed, which is what happens at the end of the day :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will provide (typically) a different hash code for each delegate.  However, [Delegate.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.gethashcode.aspx) (which is what generates a hash for any delegate) does not prohibit hash collisions.

That being said, `Dictionary<T,U>` handles hash collisions very well, and with 30 elements, you will be unlikely to have any real issues.

Comment: Thanks Reed, I just checked the implementation and it looks like they use: return base.GetType().GetHashCode(); Doesn't this mean they will have the same hash values if they have same type parameters? Like Func<int, bool> a, will be the same as Func<int, bool> b?

Comment: Thanks, I assumed with few variables to rely on, the GetHashCode would not be able to produce a unique enough hash for Func defs.

Comment: Look at MultiCastDelegate.GetHashCode() to see what actually gets used.  The hash is based on the invocation array - it is pretty good.  That being said, you can always just loop through your delegates and print out the hash codes if you want to verify that you don't have bad collisions...

Comment: @Joan: I do believe this implementation was changed in .NET 4, though - so if you're in 3.5, it's going to collide more...

Comment: Thanks Reed. I am using v4 too, but You said Delegate.GetHashCode is the one used, no? Is MultiCastDelegate.GetHashCode be used in the case of Func defs?

Comment: I have read your conversation, but i´m not sure if i can use it?

Answer (score 0):

The [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method is suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data structures such as a hash table.

You can use it for sure.  I dont see any problem in that. Thats why its there.

**Edit**

But yeah, The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects. Furthermore, the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes.

Comment: Yeah but how does it work for Func definitions? How can I find the implementation?